# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE in Button background failure

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

android Button background failure

when I try to add

```
android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
```

into the .xml

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button_stop"
     style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="3dp"
     android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:text="stop"
     android:textSize="18sp" />
```

the roundedbutton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

the button became blank and Android Studio 3.2.1 gives an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed
    at android.graphics.Canvas.checkValidClipOp(Canvas.java:779)
    at android.graphics.Canvas.clipRect(Canvas.java:826)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawShadow(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:86)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:58)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:63)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:63)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:63)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20210)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20177)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:405)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:552)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:426)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:108)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:154)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:136)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$renderInner$5(RenderTask.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can i see your @drawable/roundedbutton file ?

Comment: Reply to Batuhan: yes, I added the xml file

Comment: Are you using any custom view ?

Comment: Try removing the style attribute from the button

Comment: Reply to Vivek: I tried, the same, it showed blank

Comment: what is the parent layout of button

Comment: Reply Nikhil: LinearLayout

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> **UPDATE**

### The fix for this will be included in Android Studio 3.5 Canary 2

### [image]

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE

The  issue with `targetSdkVersion 28`

> Looks like this started being enforced in P: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#clipRect(android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Region.Op)

also reported here

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121235731
- https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/607
- https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/553
- https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/pull/588

Temporary solution for your case

Use

```
<corners
    android:radius="8dp"/>
```

instead of

```
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/>
```

Comment: I could not find bug report on Google's tracker, so I created the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121235731

Comment: @MatejDrobnič great and thanks i have added that Google's tracker,  in my answer let wait and see google response

Comment: Don't know about Canary, but this is not fixed in Android Studio 3.5 Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, (built on August 9, 2019)

Comment: Indeed. as of today, this issue still haven't been fixed. BTW, to download a more error prone compiler (and a whole new IDE), Canary, is NOT considered a 100% valid solution so you guys should watch out

Answer (score 8):

Same issue occur in my end, it was fixed now
Change the `targetSdkVersion 28 to 27` in **build.gradle**. Thanks

Comment: No need to downgrade your `targetSdkVersion` because the issue has been resolved in `Android Studio 3.5 Canary 2`

Comment: Right @NileshRathod but When user is not able to upgrade Android Studio 3.5 then change the targetSdkVersion 28 to 27

Comment: agree with you but as I said its just work around not a perfect solution

Comment: @NileshRathod I know about this. Thanks

Comment: @NileshRathod i try my project in Android Studio 3.5 Canary 2 and same error remain until now. Do you know the date release of Android Studio 3.5 stable version?

Comment: Tried 27 and 26 without luck :(

Comment: Tried also AS 3.5 Canary 6 - no luck!

Comment: I am getting this Exception from AFreeChart in its draw method.  I would expect it needs REPLACE, which is what it uses.  I have changed to AndroidX, which requires API 28 and have also implemented AppCompatActivity (because my menus in Android 9 are Black on a dark background even though they have been fine for a long time).  So going back is more than just changing back to API 27.

It would be nice if they get it fixed.

Comment: On thinking about this, the Exception I am getting is in android.graphics.Canvas.checkValidClipOp().  It happens if CompatiblityVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P(=28) and op is ERASE.  I don't see how a new version of Android Studio is going to fix that.

Comment: When will the Android Studio 3.5 release come out? How to develop when there are those issues without choosing the canary versions?

Comment: android studio 3.6.2 and problem still exists

Answer (score 8):

This is what fixed it for me:

```
.setCropShape(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P ? CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE : CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
```

Comment: I know which library you are talking about XD.

Comment: no need to do that... just update to 2.8.0 version of the library and the issue will be fixed

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who still haven't figured out how to solve this, just **Try to read the error** and understand where it stems from.

Read all the call stack, don't be afraid, line by line, and find the library which use the function `clipRect()`.

Its probably an old library which you need to updated (in my scenario, it was Lottie, which didn't report in the build.gradle that I haven't had the most recent library).

Answer (score 1):

For me it got fixed up when I changed

```
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
android:topRightRadius="8dp"
android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/>
```

to

```
<corners
android:radius="8dp"/>
```

in my buttondesign.xml file and replaced

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_verify"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_btn_bg"
        android:text="Verify"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
```

with

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_verify"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_btn_bg"
        android:text="Verify"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing " style="@android:style/Widget.Button"".

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_stop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="stop"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you encounter this problem in an activity while you do not detect the report with the solutions proposed here, it is that you use an instatble library which generates this error .. try to change the version of this library, and your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error occurred from a library i found the fix inside the issues of the corresponding github to that library