# Android (API Level 28), Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-togglebutton

I am trying to add a `ToggleButton` in design mode in Android studio.

I am targeting API Level 28 `targetSdkVersion 28`

My ToggleButton is not showing and I see that error: 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed`

Here is the `xml` of the ToggleButton

```
 <ToggleButton
            android:text="ToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="369dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp" android:id="@+id/toggleButton5" android:textOff="OFF"
            android:textOn="ON" android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" style="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat"
            tools:text="Hello" android:typeface="normal" android:textStyle="bold" android:textAlignment="center"
    />
```

Apparently [clipRect (RectF rect, Region.Op op)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#clipRect(android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Region.Op)) was deprecated in API 26, but I am not sure what needs to be changed?

And here is the complete stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed
    at android.graphics.Canvas.checkValidClipOp(Canvas.java:779)
    at android.graphics.Canvas.clipRect(Canvas.java:826)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawShadow(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:86)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:58)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:63)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:63)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20210)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20177)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:405)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:552)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:426)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:108)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:154)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:136)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$renderInner$5(RenderTask.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE in Button background failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922866/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-region-op-only-intersect-and-diffe)