# Half Rounded background with translationZ causing render problem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-shape

I want to create background for my main View where `topLeft` and `bottomLeft` corners will be rounded but right corners will be normal.

I've done this for several times for my `RecyclerView` layouts to make rounded corners for each `View`, but now it caused render error as I use `elevation` or `translationZ` to make soft shadow around the `View`.

Error: `Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed.`

I found cause of this error. It seems like Android P has some issues with corner radius as it was stated here: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE in Button background failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922866/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-region-op-only-intersect-and-diffe)

Problem is that if I apply `android:radius` it will change radius for all 4 corners what I don't want. Is there any way how to make it functional?

Here is my background xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/background_light"/>
    <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"/>
```

Comment: Maybe you can manually draw the shadow in using a layerlist in your background.xml, instead of depending on the elevation?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to manually draw the shadow into your background.xml. An advantage of this is that you then do not require the elevation. A disadvantage of this is that the shadow will be pretty sharp (like it wont have a nice gradient, but with some effort perhaps that would also be possible to draw in)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```