# Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE in Button background failure

Tags: android

When trying to add a toggle button in its most basic form:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_track"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed
```

Every question about this is marked as a duplicate of this [similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922866/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-region-op-only-intersect-and-diffe), however it seems that this is a special case where the solution lay in a deprecated use of radius in the background.

In this case, there is no background or other arguments that might cause this. What might I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Just as the solution suggests in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968428/how-to-fix-invalid-region-op-only-intersect-and-difference-are-allowed-error) post:

Update Android Studio to 3.3

Comment: I believe the linked post should be recognized as a unique post and this post marked as a duplicate of that